# Setting GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT causes crash on next frame

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am using OpenGL 3.3 and deferred shading.

When I am setting anisotropy values for my samplers between frames, the next frame causes a crash at the next frame at glClear.

Here's how I set my anisotropy values:

```
bool OpenGLRenderer::SetAnisotropicFiltering(const float newAnisoLevel)
{
    if (newAnisoLevel < 0.0f || newAnisoLevel > GetMaxAnisotropicFiltering())
        return false;

    mCurrentAnisotropy = newAnisoLevel;
    // the sampler used for geometry pass
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameterf(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, mCurrentAnisotropy));
    // the sampler used in shading pass
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameterf(mGBuffer.mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, mCurrentAnisotropy));

    return true;
}
```

The geometry pass has the following diffuse / normal textures and are setup like this:

```
    GLCALL(glUseProgram(mGeometryProgram.mProgramHandle));
    GLCALL(glGenSamplers(1, &mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT));
    GLCALL(glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(mGeometryProgram.mProgramHandle, "unifDiffuseTexture"), OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_DIFFUSE));
    GLCALL(glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(mGeometryProgram.mProgramHandle, "unifNormalTexture"), OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_NORMAL));
    GLCALL(glBindSampler(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_DIFFUSE, mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glBindSampler(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_NORMAL, mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glUseProgram(0));
```

The shading pass has the following textures for lighting calculations:

```
    GLCALL(glUseProgram(shadingProgramID));
    GLCALL(glGenSamplers(1, &mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCALL(glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shadingProgramID, "unifPositionTexture"), GBuffer::GBUFFER_TEXTURE_POSITION));
    GLCALL(glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shadingProgramID, "unifNormalTexture"), GBuffer::GBUFFER_TEXTURE_NORMAL));
    GLCALL(glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shadingProgramID, "unifDiffuseTexture"), GBuffer::GBUFFER_TEXTURE_DIFFUSE));
    GLCALL(glBindSampler(GBuffer::GBUFFER_TEXTURE_POSITION, mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glBindSampler(GBuffer::GBUFFER_TEXTURE_NORMAL, mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glBindSampler(GBuffer::GBUFFER_TEXTURE_DIFFUSE, mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glUseProgram(0));
```

And then on the next frame it crashes immediately on the glClear function when doing the geometry pass

```
void OpenGLRenderer::GeometryPass(const RenderQueue& renderQueue)
{
    GLCALL(glUseProgram(mGeometryProgram.mProgramHandle));
    GLCALL(glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, mGBuffer.mFramebuffer));

    GLCALL(glDepthMask(GL_TRUE));
    GLCALL(glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST));

    // clear GBuffer fbo
    GLCALL(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT));    // <----- crash!

    // both containers are assumed to be sorted by MeshID ascending
    auto meshIterator = mMeshes.begin();
    for (const Renderable& renderable : renderQueue)
    {
         // lots of draw code.....
    }

    GLCALL(glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST));
    GLCALL(glDepthMask(GL_FALSE));

    GLCALL(glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0));
    GLCALL(glUseProgram(0));
}
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: That was it, actually, it works with that. Make it the answer and I'll mark it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your range validation is wrong. The minimum acceptable value for anisotropy is **1.0f**. A value of **1.0f** (the default) means ***off*** (isotropic).

To be honest, rather than returning **false** and doing nothing else when you set anisotropy above or below the acceptable range, I would consider clamping the values to [1.0, MAX]. You can always find out later on that your request was unacceptable by checking the value of `mCurrentAnisotropy` after the function returns. This is useful if you store the anisotropy level as an option in a configuration file and the hardware changes. Though **16.0** is almost universally the maximum these days, some really old hardware only supports **8.0**. You can still return `false`, report a warning or whatever, but I personally always interpret a request for a level of anisotropy too high for the implementation to support to mean: "I want the highest anisotropy possible."